# Other scriptable editors?

Tags: editor, comparison

I'm just wondering what editors you know which are "scriptable". E.g take an Emacs, one can really say you can do everything from within the editor: writing,reading, programming. All with the  "scripting language" Emacs-Lisp. What other editors you know are out there as scriptable?

Do you know let's say an editor scriptable in Perl, Ruby or any other more C-like  language?

Comment: You can also try Polyad a [scriptable textpad for developers](https://polypad.io) which uses javascript and works with Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the *Windows* platform, the [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) is scriptable in the *Lua, Python, Java Script, VB Script* and *TCL* languages.

Answer (score 2):

[Yi](http://Haskell.Org/haskellwiki/Yi) is the Haskell equivalent to Emacs. It is specifically designed along the same lines as Emacs: everything is scriptable in Haskell, the editor itself is more or less just a Haskell script, and there is only a very small, very generic, non-scriptable core. In contrast to most Emacs implementations, however, which use a different language for the core than for the scripts, Yi's core is also implemented in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Vim has [Vimscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimscript) for writing plugins and extending functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[Redcar](http://RedcarEditor.Com/) is a text editor written in (mostly) Ruby, which is fully scriptable in Ruby. It is not nearly as flexible as Emacs, but more on the level of TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit and UEStudio](http://www.ultraedit.com/) have the feature to record many of its commands during a manual execution to a macro and run this macro again later. The macro can be also edited to add a loop or simple conditions.

And UltraEdit / UEStudio support also scripts. Those scripts are parsed with the JavaScript core engine. Therefore everything supported by JavaScript core like variables, arrays, string manipulations, calculations of integers or floats, nested loops, etc. can be also used in those scripts plus lots of commands of UltraEdit / UEStudio itself.

UltraEdit is available for Windows, Linux and Mac and as portable application for Windows.